# (DONE) Can we reopen the question of open plan vs offices?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Open space vs offices. Which one is better for a new team?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/128935/open-space-vs-offices-which-one-is-better-for-a-new-team)

This was closed as being *Primarily opinion based*, however given there is actual research done on this I'd suggest that it's actually not the case.

I was actually typing up an a suitably referenced answer when it was closed!

Comment: One more needed

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see the asker talk about which criteria are key.  "Better" is in the eye of the beholder, but "better, given this budget, this team size, these work functions" (or whatever) is solidly answerable.

The existing answers do a good job of responding to that vague premise, so I won't object if it gets reopened, but I'd really prefer to see more information in the question, which is why I'm not casting a reopen vote myself.

Answer (score 1):

The question is still primarily opinion based. Research does not answer which one is "better", it answers differences in variables like "amount of communication between coworkers measured by X metric" or "productivity measured in Y metric".

I see it is already reopened so leaving this here in case it is closed back, which is appropriate here.